# Resizing the table content inside Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a simple modal using Bootstrap to allow users to look at the table contents. However, I am having a problem trying to keep the table contents inside the modal.

When I reduce the size of the website/modal, the table contents would go outside the modal. Is there any way I can make the users to scroll so that they can see all the table contents inside?

This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/otw8v3ex/60/) code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#complex">Button</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="complex" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Test</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table id="example" class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>ID Number</th>
              <th>Proband</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Birth Date</th>
              <th>Life Status</th>
              <th>Phenotype</th>
              <th>Genotype</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want scroll on your modal container, then you can go with css only.
Look for fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/oq0xLmz2/

```
.modal-body {
    overflow : auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#complex">Button</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="complex" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Test</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="table table-responsive">
          <table id="example">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>ID Number</th>
                <th>Proband</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Birth Date</th>
                <th>Life Status</th>
                <th>Phenotype</th>
                <th>Genotype</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```